# Form Validation And Redirecting In Flask Without Extensions (WTForms, etc)

Tags: html, forms, validation, flask

I've been searching and reading dozens of posts and yet to find an answer.

I'm looking for a way to validate a form, stay on the same page and present error upon failure, or render the next html page if successful.

My current try: Sending the form to flask, validating and redirecting. The hidden frame is so the page won't refresh if validation fails. For some reason render_template doesn't work and err won't show.

Python and Html (simplified):

```js
@app.route("/", methods=['POST'])
def validate_form():
    print 
    if (format(request.form['q1']) != '1' or format(request.form['q2']) != '2 ):
        return render_template("index.html",err = "One of your answers are incorrect. Please check again.")
    else:
        return render_template("next_page.html")
```

```html
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" class="hide"></iframe>

                <form name ="quiz" method="post" action="/" target="hiddenFrame">

                    <p>Who likes carrots?<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" checked>bunny<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2">rabbit<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3">beyonce<br>
                    </p>
                    <p>what is 1+1?<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" checked>10<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2">1.<br>
                    <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3">2<br>
                    </p>
                   
                <span class="error">* {{err}}</span><br>             
                <input class="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
                </form>
```

Edit: My HTML page is divided into 3-4 sub-contents, where you click on "next" and "prev" buttons to move across them. When the user submits the form, I need it to stay on the same sub-content, so I used a hidden frame to redirect back to it via html. I belive that some solution that I did is not working properly in terms of letting the page render itself..

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you'll want to wrap your current if statements in an overarching

```
if flask.request.method == POST:
```

This will activate the code when it's posted.

Next you'll want to use flashes for messages being displayed if information isn't correct. Give it a quick google and you should be able to find a quick template to use.

Comment: You are correct with the wrapping but my function only accept POST requests. The code works. The lines that won't work is render_template/redirect. I'm sure I'm missing something, maybe in the logic of flask+python+html but this whole topic is new to me so I didn't have time to learn its connections deeply.

Comment: Take a look at the link below. It should help with what you want to do.


http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/flashing/

Comment: Two things. 1) Try preappending render_template with flask. (flask.render_template) and 2) Can you repost what you currently have. Both py and html

Comment: This is really all I have... I removed additional input buttons and some debug printing,etc from my original code. Let me add something about my html that I believe can lead to an answer. check my edit

Comment: I don't see anything in your code about flashes, so I can't really help on that.

Comment: Srry for the delay. I did a couple of things with flash messages before and I tried the same thing here before I came asking for a solution. I also tried again when u advised me to